# Как реализовать разные стили в Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, style

Знаю что в `HTML` для стилей используется `CSS`, находящийся в отдельной папке, при этом стили можно менять. В данный момент тренируюсь в создании программы с помощью `GUI Tkinter`, хотел попробовать реализовать несколько стиле окна на выбор.

То есть надо сделать несколько файлов в которых будут храниться настройки стилей для программы и сохранение настроек пользователя после закрытия программы, но к сожалению не знаю как это реализовать.

Причины:

1. Не представляю как составляются стили для окна на `Tkinter`
2. Не знаю как сохранять в программе какой стиль выбран

Подскажите, как можно реализовать такую задумку или какие доки/литературу/учебники почитать?

Comment: Наверное единственное, что есть в tkinter для расширения стандартных стилей это ttk (p.s никто не мешает создать файл с интерфейсом, а после к нему подключить модулями, то что нужно).

Comment: @Дмитрий, я знаю о ttk, но мне бы хотелось создать специальные файлы, при использовании которых менялись бы бэкграунды всех виджетов, шрифт ну и тд. Может есть идейки по реализации такого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Короче, рассказываю всё по порядку.

1. Скачиваем библиотеку ttkthemes
2. Заходим в папку этой библиотеки и там есть папка themes с папками, в которых tcl файлы. Именно там и находятся все темы(каждая в своей папке)

3)Чтобы всё работало хорошо копируем файл `pkgindex.tcl` в папку со своей темой и меняем под название своей темы

4. Находим `pkgindex.tcl` в папке со всеми темами и там добавляем имя package своей темы

С помощью этих действий я смог установить темы, про которые спрашивал очень давно. Также получилось менять цвета этих тем и создавать новые основываясь на них.

В качестве доказательства в комментарии залью ссылку на Google Диск с обновленной библиотекой(в архиве `.zip`). Там я добавил тему `breeze` все мои шаги сможете проверить пошарившись в указанных файлах

UPD Папка была удалена при чисте Google Диска. Извиняюсь)